# Update OS X to El Capitan and Core Plot crashes :(

Tags: macos, crash, core-plot, osx-elcapitan

Updated my OS for 10.11
Tried to run my project that was working fine on Yosemite
But something strange with core plot
here is a crash log, any ideas?

> 2015-10-02 00:18:48.097 checkMyMac[2410:186855] *** -[**NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil 2015-10-02 00:18:48.098
>   checkMyMac[2410:186855] (     0   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff95f55bd2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff9bc284fa objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff95e6c370 checkForCloseTag + 0   3   CorePlot
>
>   0x0000000100108a79 CPTPushCGContext + 169     4   CorePlot
>
>   0x0000000100108938
>   -[NSAttributedString(CPTPlatformSpecificAttributedStringExtensions) drawInRect:inContext:] + 40   5   CorePlot
>
>   0x00000001000f6016 -[CPTTextLayer renderAsVectorInContext:] + 694     6
>
>   CorePlot                            0x00000001000f70f5 -[CPTLayer
>   drawInContext:] + 85  7   QuartzCore
>
>   0x00007fff9681fcdd _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 649  8   CorePlot
>
>   0x00000001000f708b -[CPTLayer display] + 91   9   QuartzCore
>
>   0x00007fff96811e51 _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE
>   + 603     10  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff96811979 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 35   11  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff96810e4d
>   _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277   12  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff96810a98
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508    13  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff9681c28f
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 71     14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff95eeae07
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff95eead77
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391  16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff95ec9d58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 328   17  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff8a4e0d55 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235    18  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff8a4e0a97 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 184   19  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff8a4e09cf _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter +
>   71    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8aed2f3a
>   _DPSNextEvent + 1067  21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8aed2369 -[NSApplication
>   _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454  22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8aec6ecc -[NSApplication
>   run] + 682    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ae90162
>   NSApplicationMain + 1176  24  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff8c85f5ad start + 1  25  ???
>   0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3

Downloaded a new copy of core plot from git hub
Compiled as Framework and same story :-(

Okay So I modified the source code
if some one will have the same problem here is my (not so great solution

In file named CPTTextLayer.m

```
-(void)renderAsVectorInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    if ( self.hidden ) {
        return;
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Added by me to avoid crash when self.text
    // or self.attributedText is nil
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (!self.text || !self.attributedText)
    {
        return;
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    NSString *myText = self.text;
    if ( myText.length > 0 ) {
        [super renderAsVectorInContext:context];

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CPTFloat(0.0), self.bounds.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM( context, CPTFloat(1.0), CPTFloat(-1.0) );
#endif

        CGRect newBounds = CGRectInset(self.bounds, kCPTTextLayerMarginWidth, kCPTTextLayerMarginWidth);
        newBounds.origin.x += self.paddingLeft;
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        newBounds.origin.y += self.paddingTop;
#else
        newBounds.origin.y += self.paddingBottom;
#endif
        newBounds.size.width  -= self.paddingLeft + self.paddingRight;
        newBounds.size.height -= self.paddingTop + self.paddingBottom;



        NSAttributedString *styledText = self.attributedText;




        if ( (styledText.length > 0) && [styledText respondsToSelector:@selector(drawInRect:)] ) {
            [styledText drawInRect:newBounds
                         inContext:context];
        }
        else {
            [myText drawInRect:newBounds
                 withTextStyle:self.textStyle
                     inContext:context];
        }

    #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    #endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that has already been fixed on the release-2.0 branch. See Core Plot [issue #210](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/210) for details.